# Remove duplicates python

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone help me removing duplicates from reading a file

```
def listaClientes():
    f = open("chamadas.txt","r").readlines()
    print("Clientes que fizeram chamadas: ")
    new_lines = []
    for line in f:
        parts = line.strip().split()
        chamada = (parts[0])
        print(chamada)
```

It gives me this (parts)

```
Clients: 
960373347, 960373347,930930597, 960373347,939999868
```

As you can see i have numbers repeated, how to prevent this in python?

Thanks

Comment: `set(parts)` will return the unique entries in the `parts` `list`.

Comment: if all you want is to remove the duplicates from the list use ; def remove_duplicates(l):
    return list(set(l))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything to remove duplicates.
use a set to keep only unique values.

Try this:

```
def listaClientes():
  f = open("chamadas.txt","r").readlines()
  print("Clientes que fizeram chamadas: ")
  new_lines = set()
  for line in f:
    parts = line.strip().split()
    chamada = (parts[0])
    lines = new_lines.add
    return [cli for cli in chamada if not (cli in new_lines or lines(cli))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def listaClientes():
    f = open("chamadas.txt", "r").readlines()
    print("Clientes que fizeram chamadas: ")
    new_lines = []
    for line in f:
        parts = line.strip().split()
        chamada = (parts[0])
        if chamada not in new_lines:#here checking if there any exesting entry
            new_lines.append(chamada)
        print(chamada)
    #at last new_lines have the unique entries
```

Answer (score 0):

Well known Python trick:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
>>> list(set(l))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```